# Facebook graph V2.12 : always send the same number of fan_count

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I try some scripts (from scratch https call or libraries) and I am always in the case where fan_count doesn't change.
with a browser it is OK
with postman the fan_count number doesn't change.
with scripts (from scratch or with libraries), nodejs, php, etc.. it also doesnt't change:

my request is :
[https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/663065333785499?access_token=**MY_ACCESS_TOKEN**&fields=fan_count](https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/663065333785499?access_token=__MY_ACCESS_TOKEN__&fields=fan_count)

Do you now any working way ?

I put two scripts with the same aim:
Get the fan_count number of my facebook business page.
The issue is exactly the same : the fan_count number stay blocked at a given value even if you like or dislike the concerned facevook business page. The first is "from scratch" (nodejs).
The secund use a PHP library (see script)

I just want to have a technical solution to get the fan_count number of a facebook business page (V2.12). I really don't care about the language, library : it must work.

2 scripts example:

In case of using an another library (php) : "facebook/graph-sdk":"^5.6"

```html
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php'; // change path as needed

$fb = new \Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => '__APP_ID__',
    'app_secret' => '__APP_SECRET__',
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.12',
    //'default_access_token' => '{access-token}', // optional
]);

// Use one of the helper classes to get a Facebook\Authentication\AccessToken entity.
//   $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
//   $helper = $fb->getJavaScriptHelper();
//   $helper = $fb->getCanvasHelper();
//   $helper = $fb->getPageTabHelper();

try {
    // Get the \Facebook\GraphNodes\GraphUser object for the current user.
    // If you provided a 'default_access_token', the '{access-token}' is optional.
    //$fb->getApp()->getId().'|'.$fb->getApp()->getSecret()
    $response = $fb->get('/663065333785499?fields=fan_count', $fb->getApp()->getAccessToken()->getValue());
} catch(\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    // When Graph returns an error
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
} catch(\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}

die(var_dump($response));
```

Another script in nodejs

```js
var express = require('express');
var cookieSession = require('cookie-session');
var setCookie = require('set-cookie-parser');


var app = express();
app.use(cookieSession({
    name: 'session',
    keys: [/* secret keys */],

    // Cookie Options
    maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 // 24 hours
}))

const https = require('https');

var host = 'graph.facebook.com';
var path = '/v2.12/663065333785499?access_token=__ACCESS_TOKEN__&fields=fan_count';
var headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36',
    'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Accept' : 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-language': 'fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,ro;q=0.6',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Upgrade-insecure-requests': 1,
};

var optionsget = {
    headers: headers,
    host: host,
    path: path,
    method: 'GET'
};


https.get(optionsget, (res) => {

    var cookies = setCookie.parse(res, {
        decodeValues: true  // default: true
    });

    res.on('data', (d) => {
        process.stdout.write(d);
    });

}).on('error', (e) => {
    console.error(e);
});
```

Comment: if a specific script returns the wrong number, the first thing to do is to show us the script...

Comment: So it is done. Thanks.

Comment: ...why would you post your script as answer, and in 2 different ones? you need to edit your question instead..

Comment: Your are right..

Answer (score 0):

```js
var express = require('express');
var cookieSession = require('cookie-session');
var setCookie = require('set-cookie-parser');


var app = express();
app.use(cookieSession({
    name: 'session',
    keys: [/* secret keys */],

    // Cookie Options
    maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 // 24 hours
}))

const https = require('https');

var host = 'graph.facebook.com';
var path = '/v2.12/663065333785499?access_token=__ACCESS_TOKEN__&fields=fan_count';
var headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36',
    'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Accept' : 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-language': 'fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,ro;q=0.6',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Upgrade-insecure-requests': 1,
};

var optionsget = {
    headers: headers,
    host: host,
    path: path,
    method: 'GET'
};


https.get(optionsget, (res) => {

    var cookies = setCookie.parse(res, {
        decodeValues: true  // default: true
    });

    res.on('data', (d) => {
        process.stdout.write(d);
    });

}).on('error', (e) => {
    console.error(e);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of using an another library (php) : "facebook/graph-sdk":"^5.6"

```html
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php'; // change path as needed

$fb = new \Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => '__APP_ID__',
    'app_secret' => '__APP_SECRET__',
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.12',
    //'default_access_token' => '{access-token}', // optional
]);

// Use one of the helper classes to get a Facebook\Authentication\AccessToken entity.
//   $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
//   $helper = $fb->getJavaScriptHelper();
//   $helper = $fb->getCanvasHelper();
//   $helper = $fb->getPageTabHelper();

try {
    // Get the \Facebook\GraphNodes\GraphUser object for the current user.
    // If you provided a 'default_access_token', the '{access-token}' is optional.
    //$fb->getApp()->getId().'|'.$fb->getApp()->getSecret()
    $response = $fb->get('/663065333785499?fields=fan_count', $fb->getApp()->getAccessToken()->getValue());
} catch(\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    // When Graph returns an error
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
} catch(\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}

die(var_dump($response));
```